# How to calculate the complexity of the following code?

Tags: time-complexity

I want to know the complexity of the following code after I add a judgment condition

```matlab
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        if () %Judge whether the following loop execution is executed
            for l=1:n 
                for m=1:n
                    ;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey! I have two questions for you: What kind of time complexity are you looking for? The answer will depend if you're looking for average, best or worse case complexity. And also do you assume your conditional (if) statement depends on i and j or on other external variables?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.